# Fortran Makefile Error and Questions

Tags: makefile, fortran

I'm trying to make my own Makefile for a Fortran code. It looks very alike to another Makefile, which can perfectly work. But unfortunately I can't find out what's wrong by myself. The configuration is described below:

I have a main folder containing sub-folders name src, lib, results, mod, obj. Makefile itself is also in the main folder. I have several fortran sources files in the src folder, say main.f90, subroutine_1.f90, subroutine_2.f90, module_1.f90 and module_2.f90. Subroutine_1 and subroutine_2 are included in module_1, module_2 in also used in module_1. In this case I only need main.f90 and module_*.f90 to be included in my Makefile(if that's not wrong). I also have a static library to be used.

```
# For WINDOWS
RM          :=  del
PS          :=  $(strip \)

#--------------------- DICTIONARY ---------------------
BUILD_DIR   :=  .       
SRC_DIR     :=  $(BUILD_DIR)$(PS)src
LIB_DIR     :=  -L$(BUILD_DIR)$(PS)lib
TAR_DIR     :=  $(BUILD_DIR)$(PS)results
MOD_DIR     :=  $(BUILD_DIR)$(PS)mod
OBJ_DIR     :=  $(BUILD_DIR)$(PS)obj

#------------------ COMPILER AND FLAG ------------------
FC          :=  gfortran
FCFLAGS     := -g -c -fbacktrace -fno-align-commons -fbounds-check\
                -J"$(MOD_DIR)"
FLFLAGS     :=

#------------------- TARGET & SOURCE--------------------
TARGET      :=  $(TAR_DIR)$(PS)main.exe
SRC         :=  $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)$(PS)module_*.f90))\
                main.f90
LIB         :=  -lfftw3-3.lib
LDFLAGS     :=  $(LIB_DIR)   
OBJ         :=  $(patsubst %.f90, $(OBJ_DIR)$(PS)%.o, $(notdir $(SRC)))

all:    $(TARGET)
# Final linking
$(TARGET):  $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB)   #line a

$(OBJ_DIR)$(PS)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)$(PS)%.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $<                         #line b

clean:   
    -$(RM) -f $(OBJ_DIR)$(PS)*.o
    -$(RM) -f $(MOD_DIR)$(PS)*.mod
```

I got many errors from the make process but I guess they all come from the same place.

```
$ make
Makefile:line a: warning: overriding recipe for target '.'
Makefile:line b: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.'
make: Circular . <- . dependency dropped.
make: *** No rule to make target 'src\%.f90', needed by '.'.  Stop.
```

Except from the error, I also have several questions:

1. How to choose appropriate flags for compiling?
2. Since module_2 is used in module_1, do I need to compile them in order? In reality I have many modules so I don't think I'm able to specify that one by one...
3. When do I need to create a dependency .d file? I don't quite know how it works.
4. Do I need to compile .mod out of .o? For example add a line
   %.mod: %.o

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have multiple space characters in `BUILD_DIR   :=  .       ` after the period, get rid of them.

Comment: The flags depend on what you want. If debugging, `-g`, `-fbacktrace` and `-fcheck-bounds` are useful. I normally use too `-Wall` and `-fcheck=all`. If you want your code to run faster you might want to use an optimisation such as `-03` and get rid of the debugging flags.

Comment: Also, looks like you have a circular dependency, which is not good. You should try to avoid such thing. And answering your question - yes, you do need to compile them in order. Have a look if this solves de problem.

Comment: @ b-fg Thank you. Could you explain more why I have a circular dependency? I don't quite understand ths part

Comment: Check it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). So basically you have a module A which calls module B and a module B which calls module A at the same time. You should avoid this type of practice.